# nginx redirect all https requests to local https portal

Tags: redirect, nginx, https, url-rewriting, http-status-code-302

I have local portal (captive portal), which is https and redirecting all http requests to local https works fine. 
But redirecting requests from https to local https portal doesn't work at all.
Here how I configured nginx:

```
upstream flask_portal {
    server unix:/tmp/flask_portal.sock;
}

server {
    listen 172.31.3.1:443 default_server;
    rewrite ^(.*) https://my_site.com?url=$server_name$1;
}

server {
    listen 172.31.3.1:80 default_server;
    listen 172.31.3.1:443 ssl;
    server_name my_site.com;
    ssl_certificate      my_site.com.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key  my_site.com.key;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass flask_portal;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

When I test it with curl to https://www.google.com
it reports:

```
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.googlw.com:443
```

I think nginx should redirect www.google com to my_site.com and curl should ask my_site certificate, but it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** redirect https, because your certificate does not match www.google.com or *.google.com and so the browser (rightfully) will fail to to handshake with it. Curl (and your browser) will never even see the redirect, as that would require a successful handshake.

What you **can** do is **tell the browser that you are a captive portal** : https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/network-portal-detection

Comment: Mobile devices detect captive portal well, as does some operation systems (Elementary OS, for example), and chrome browser does it too.
And they work very good.


But some browsers does not detect captive portal (Firefox, as an example), therefore if someone uses this kind of browsers, he will get SSL error page instead of portal page. So user might not understand, that to get internet he needs to open any HTTP link, and will just close web browser.


I didn't success to find any solution for this problem.
@jdewald, thank you for answer. I'll just spot wasting my to resolve it.

Comment: If Firefox doesn't detect captive portal ( https://wiki.mozilla.org/Necko/CaptivePortal ) you can't solve the problem for https webpages : FF think you're in the web, and it's not the server you ask that answer, thus, it's an attack, a red message will show up.